# Can i exclude spaces from text decoration?

Tags: css, sass, text-decorations, line-through

Maybe my question is too simple :) Struggling to exclude `&snbsp` and spaces from being visualized with strike through:

```
del {
    text-decoration: line-through;
    background-color: var(--color-warn-light);
}
```

So in `<del>&nbsp</del>` the space is not visualized like a minus '-'.

Is there a possibility that CSS can be used to exclude some characters from being decorated?

**Update**: found `text-decoration-skip: spaces` by its is not supported by most browsers :(

Comment: its not possible with CSS only

Comment: @dippas and not by css only?

Comment: Do you want the background to show on the spaces still?

Comment: @AHaworth yes, background shall be warn color

Comment: Please consider accepting an answer if it solved your problem or helped in finding the solution.

Answer (score 1):

### Inline Block

You can wrap the space in a span with display set to inline-block:

```css
 span {
   display: inline-block;
 }
```

```html
<del>text<span>&nbsp</span>text</del>
```

### Selector :not

```css
span:not(.space) {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<span>text</span>
<span class="space">&nbsp</span>
<span>text</span>
```

### JavaScript

Or you can use some simple JavaScript:

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll("del");
for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  const elem = elements[i];
  const words = elem.innerText.split(/\s/);
  elem.innerHTML = words.join("<span>&nbsp;</span>")
}
```

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<del>text&nbsp;text</del>
<del>text text</del>
```

Comment: Very clean JS! Nicely done.

Comment: This seems to replace all the 'ordinary' spaces with non-breaking spaces which could cause problems in some circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

As you and @dippas figured out, this is currently not supported via pure CSS across all browsers.

I suggest doing this with JavaScript, by splitting the text you are interested in at the space character into separate span elements. You can then apply your `line-through` decoration to the span elements, which will not include the spaces.

Here is a simple example:

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll("del");
for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  const elem = elements[i];
  const words = elem.innerText.split(" ");
  const spans = words.map((word) => {
    const span = document.createElement("span");
    span.innerText = word;
    return span;
  });
  
  elem.innerHTML = "";
  spans.forEach((span) => {
    elem.appendChild(span);
    elem.innerHTML += "&nbsp;";
  });
}
```

```css
del {
  text-decoration: none;
}

del span {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <del>All the text to be marked through here</del>
  <br />
  <del>Additional text to be marked through here</del>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice, I hope you don't mind this inspired me to use some JS in combination with my solution.

Comment: @H3AR7B3A7 of course not! We're all on the same team here, it isn't a competition :) nice answer!